# How to use Edit Text as URL Hotbar in Android Studio?

Tags: android, url

Is there a way, to use a edit text field as a URL Hotbar in Android Studio.
I'm a beginner, so I don't know so much, but I'm learning.

Thank you.

Comment: What is an 'url hotbar'?

Comment: That's where you type in the URL in a browser.

Comment: You want to integrate a browser into your app? Or just an edittext that you can use as searchbar to search in a list for example?

Comment: Yes, I would like to use the edit text as a search bar.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a search feature from the EditText value you can do that easily. Simply get the text from the EditText and append this https://www.google.com/search?q= before the EditText value,

```
EditText search_key = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editSearchBar);
String key = search_key.getText.ToString();

WebView webview=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview); 
webview.loadUrl( "https://www.google.com.bd/search?q=" + key);
```

This will display a Google search result on your WebView.

Comment: I mean, to use it like in Google chrome. To enter a URL of any site to get there.

Comment: Just take the value from the EditText and convert in to string then load the page by webview.loadUrl( edittext_value.toString); The default WebView will start loading the url.